# Pick data from another sheet in specific row intervals

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sheet that picks values from a different sheet (raw data sheet). Best to show through an example.

```
        Col1                
Row1    [anothersheet.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$14
Row2    [anothersheet.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$141
Row3    [anothersheet.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$268
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

Each next row in the current sheet needs to pick data from the the next 127th row of the data sheet. Is there a way to do this simplistically without any programming? Right now its just one column but there will be other columns added soon and they'll show data the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In Cell A1 you can use the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("[anothersheet.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$"&ROW()*127-113,TRUE)
```

You can adjust the math accordingly to meet any other needs you have.